# How to know where some bean configuration was loaded?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I'm writing a program to check whether the source code submitted by students meet all requirements given in the exercise description.

Now if some bean is required to must be configured from XML file, how can I check it without parsing the XML configuration file? Can I get the related information from spring container at runtime?

Thanks!

Comment: Bean definition using annotation are not supported?

Comment: get the bean from ApplicationContext

Comment: @AbdulRahman Sorry, my question is not clear. I have updated my question. It is required that bean must be created by the configuration in the xml file.

Comment: @walsh If you have a container, you can check if the container is bases on XML file.

Comment: @user27149 how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the bean is found as follows:

```
BeanDefinition beanDefinition = context.getBeanDefinition("someBean");
beanDefinition.getResourceDescription();  // Will describe if the XML file is the source
```

Example:

1. The XML file (stripped down for clarity) which is named **app-config.xml**:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans ...>
       <bean name="someBean" class="com.stackoverflow.aopdemo.service.StudentImpl" 
   />
   </beans>
   ```
2. Skeleton program showing usage:

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   @ImportResource("classpath:app-config.xml") 
   public class DemoApplication {

      @Autowired
      private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
       }

       @PostConstruct
       public void init() {
          BeanDefinition beanDefinition = context.getBeanDefinition("someBean");
          String resourceDescription = beanDefinition.getResourceDescription();
          System.out.println("Resource Description = "+resourceDescription);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Produces the following output (showing the xml file name):

   ```
   Resource Description = class path resource [app-config.xml]
   ```

Comment: It does not work.  I tested it but it returned `null`

Comment: The beanDefinition existed, but getResourceDescription() was null?  Strange, it worked for me.  I will test further tomorrow.  Hopefully you get another answer tonight.  Cheers.